# What setup to use with a shotgun condenser microphone to record on a laptop?

Tags: homerecording, microphones

I've been using a USB headset and an external web camera both connected to a laptop to record educational videos. The way I record the videos is by looking directly at the web camera which is located on top of an external monitor connected to a laptop. A visual example can be seen in an example photo below.

[image: Here is a visual example]

I'd like to stop wearing a headset, and instead, record using a microphone. There are great USB microphones and Lavalier microphones out there such as the Rode SmartLav+, but I have an sE Electronics ProMic Laser microphone lying around not being used and I'd like to put it to use if possible instead of buying another microphone.

Would it be feasible to create a setup that would allow this microphone to be used for such a purpose and for those who know all the ins and outs of this topics, what accessories would you recommend getting? Can this microphone go on a swivel mount and be placed just next to the external web camera? Would anything else be needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for that not to work, the best is always to try ;).

This microphone is fitted with 3.5mm Jack which you can normally fit straight in the microphone input of your computer. If your computer is fitted with a combined jack (4-rings, manage loudspeakers and a microphone through one jack) then you will [need an adaptator](https://blog.startech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/MUYHSMFF.E.jpg).

[This mic](https://www.seelectronics.com/promic-laser) seems to be hypercadoid: it get nearly only the sound which is coming in front of it, so you need to place it just in front of you. With such a directional mic, it will be hard to get feedback but still: do not put your loudspeakers facing the mic (in your back).

Comment: The information you provided is helpful and interesting. I will position right next to the web camera. And I am curious, when you say it will be hard to get feedback, does feedback, in this case, mean the microphone catching other sounds? I am planning to run the microphone through the Nvidia RTX voice software to eliminate any noise from outside.

Comment: I meant feedback, in term of this horrible squeaky noise you sometimes have in sonorized events. It does happen if the mic is catching the sound from the loudspeakers, creating a loop (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_feedback). This is annoying, but as your mic is really directional you should not have any problems ;).